# Is it possible to resize RSS feed images

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net

I have implementing the RSS news feed into my ASP.net application,but the images size of news increase the page size and page gets loaded very slowly.

I want to re-size images of `RSS news` images without loosing images quality

```
<div id="divNewsFeed" style="float: left;">
        <marquee id="ml" style="text-align: left; width: 100%; height: 110px;" direction="up" scrolldelay="20" scrollamount="1" onmouseover="stop();" onmouseout="start();">                


                <table style="border: solid 1px ridge; font-family: Arial">

                    <tbody><tr>
                        <td style="font-weight: bold;">
                            <a id="MainContent_UCOnlineNewsFeeds1_rssRepeater_HyperLink1_0" href="http://www.ibnlive.com/news/india/sheena-bora-murder-case-peter-mukerjea-making-conflicting-statements-say-reports-1168342.html" target="_blank" style="color:Red;">Sheena Bora murder case: Peter Mukerjea making conflicting statements, say reports</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <span id="MainContent_UCOnlineNewsFeeds1_rssRepeater_Label1_0"><img src="http://img01.ibnlive.in/ibnlive/uploads/2015/11/petermails_pkg_2.jpg" width="40px" height="40px">According to sources, Peter Mukerjea is not cooperating and is making conflicting statements. </span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody></table>

                <table style="border: solid 1px ridge; font-family: Arial">

                    <tbody><tr>
                        <td style="font-weight: bold;">
                            <a id="MainContent_UCOnlineNewsFeeds1_rssRepeater_HyperLink1_1" href="http://www.ibnlive.com/news/india/prime-minister-narendra-modi-india-is-a-living-example-of-vasudhaiva-kutumbakam-1168334.html" target="_blank" style="color:Red;">Modi woos Singapore with reforms card, says FDI is 'first develop India'</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <span id="MainContent_UCOnlineNewsFeeds1_rssRepeater_Label1_1"><img src="http://img01.ibnlive.in/ibnlive/uploads/2015/11/modi_live_singapore_2.jpg" width="40px" height="40px">There is a lot that Singapore can teach u and the one example is cleanliness, says PM Modi</span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody></table></div>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide more information? Post the HTML/CSS you have.  It's possible to resize images using CSS, but without specific code to look at this question is too vague for an answer.

Comment: Well, use a compressed image file format, `png`, `gif` or `jpg`.